# Overwriting SVN Trunk to Branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I force overwrite trunk to an existing branch, with keeping Revision log of the branch? I need this because I want to reset the branch to the head revision of the trunk for another work.

Here's an example what I ask: There is a trunk and a branch 001.

```
/trunk
/branches
    /001
```

Here's the history.

- Copied trunk to the branch 001. (Revision 10)
- 001 is changed. (Revision 11)
- Trunk is also changed. (Revision 12)
- Merged trunk to 001. (Revision 13)
- 001 is changed. (Revision 14)
- Trunk is changed (Revision 15)

Now, I want to revert all changes in 001 and copy the latest revision of trunk to 001.

There is `svn copy` command, but it also removes Revision history in 001. I don't want that.

I tried `svn merge --reintegrate`, but it mixes theirs and mine in each file, so it is useless.

I tried `svn merge --ignore-ancestry`, but it shows many Tree Conflicts and nothing is copied from to 001.

What is a good way for overwriting the head revision of the trunk to the branch 001?

Comment: You can try to do it in two steps : 1) Revert branch 001 to revision 10.  2) Merge revisions 12 and 15 to branch 001.

Comment: @LaurentH. Thank for your answer. I tried following your answer, however, it takes too much time for SVN to finish it.